# Okay to delete certain Java files on Mac?

Tags: mac, java

I have a gigabyte worth of Java files on my computer that I don't think I need.  They come in three flavors:

1. `/Users/Me/Library/Application Support/Java/Java 1.8.66.17/Java 8 Update 66.app`
2. `/Users/Me/Library/Application Support/Java/Java 1.8.101.13/jre-8u101-fcs-bin-b13-macosx-x86_64-21_jun_2016_au.dmg`
3. `/Users/Me/Library/Application Support/Java/Java 1.8.45.14 2/JavaAppletPlugin.pkg`

From what I know, `.pkg` files (and maybe `.dmg` files) are only used for installation, so I don't need them.  Also, I think I only need the most recent version of the `.app` file.

Will someone stop me before I shamelessly delete all these files?  (Which of these files can I safely delete?)

Comment: hmmm... prompted me to have a look... 14 distinct versions, 1.44GB. Does seems a bit of a waste of space.

Answer (score 2):

The java installation/update files in your **home** Library folder are **safe to delete**. Especially the specific ones you are listing.

Anything under /System/Library/Java/ or /Library/Java is probably better to left alone unless you know what you're doing or use a officially documented uninstall procedure.

edit: If an application will need to have java installed (i.e. happened to me with an old adobe program) you can install it again!